# XSL -if combination with attribute

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt

Hi everybody i have a litle problem with xsl. I have a basic document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div type="letter">
<head>
<persName type="creator" xml:id="ID.14">
            <forename>Theodor</forename>
            <surname>Billroth</surname>
          </persName>
          <persName type="addressee" xml:id="ID.15">
            <forename>Alexander</forename>
            <surname>Rollett</surname>
</persName>
<persName type="creator" xml:id="ID.16">
            <forename>Chris</forename>
            <surname>Billroth</surname>
          </persName>
          <persName type="addressee" xml:id="ID.17">
            <forename>Phil</forename>
            <surname>Rollett</surname>
</persName>
</head>
</div>
```

I got some advice and edited the code a little bid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="//head">
        <div>
          <head>
                 <xsl:for-each select="//persName[@type='creator']">
                 <xsl:text> From </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="forename"/>
                        <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
                        <!--it is woking until here  -->
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
           </head>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At the moment the Output is looking like this:

```
 <div><head> From Theodor to  From Chris to </head></div>
```

I expect or better i want to generate an output which hits the creator attribute and if it hits it should add the forename. then jump down , add to select the forename from the addresssee. and the output should look like this:

```
From Theodor To Alexander 
and
From Christian to Phil
```

ok the and is an option. I hope you have a solution for that. Cheers

Comment: Do they always come in pairs: creator followed by addressee? Note that your indenting is misleading: all the `persName` nodes are siblings. And xml:id is supposed to be unique, I believe.

Comment: For best practice, there should some unique mapping for "creator" and "addressee" to know which "addressee" is mapped with which "creator".

Comment: @Mchoeti Did you not see this part: `<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::persName[1]/forename"/>`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have seen that but i don`t know why it is not working... i tried it without the template and also no success

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you, you did a great job, i think it is only an namespace problem, i will solve that later.... thank you... and if i got it i will post the answer thank you, good luck and good night

Comment: ok, got it, it was a adressing problem from my side your solution ist working perfect. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your starting point. It will work with your example input, assuming that after every creator comes an addressee.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/head">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="persName[@type='creator']">
                <xsl:text>From </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="forename"/>
                <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::persName[1]/forename"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>and</xsl:text>
                    <br/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: yes you are right it is workin, but only for my first part, i don`t know why.

<!--it is woking until here i think  -->
 <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::persName[1]/forename"/> 
  <!--and the second part is not workin  -->

the output is:
From Theodor to
From Christian to

Comment: @Mchoeti **1.** Please don't post code in comments - if necessary, edit your question. -- **2.** My answer is based on the code you have posted. If your actual code is different ...

Comment: i know i knwo... i recordnized it too late sorry

Comment: thank you for giving me some advice, i really appreciate that, maybe you can gie me one more little help, i updated the question and closed the others. if i got more then one element, how should i solve this ?